# Can't add inspector variables to script?

Tags: c#, unity

So I just added this script to my project : https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11278 Since this script only draws the lines on gizmos, I wanted to add a LineRenderer, so that I can draw the lines also in GameView. So I simply wrote :

`public LineRenderer lr;`

But this variable never appears in my inspector, can anybody explain me why this happens and how I could fix it?

Comment: there are 4 scripts in that asset. On which one exactly did you put that line ?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that ! I guess that could even be the problem. I'm working on BezierCurve.cs

Comment: Yeah thanks you helped me actually with that question...I just found out, that I have to add the field in both files the "BezierCurve" and "BezierCurveEditor"....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script BezierCurveEditor is overwriting the GUI Layout of the component because of this line right at the top of file : `[CustomEditor(typeof(BezierCurve))]`

Adding a line renderer prop to the OnEnable and OnInspectorGUI fixes the issue.

```
SerializedProperty colorProp;
    void OnEnable()
    {
    linerendereProp = serializedObject.FindProperty("lr");
}
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();


        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(linerendereProp);
}
```